# Recursive Range Output from Max and Min

Tags: java, range, max, min

Hello there i am very new to java coding (Beginner level) and i am learning how to use recursive but i am doing a bit of practice where i am using a min and max value to get the range.

I want the output to be like if min is 2 and max is 10 it print 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 as the output. It print out in between min and max also but i don't how i am actually stuck getting the output.

**BELOW ARE THE CODE:**

```
//package methods;
public class MethodsRecursiveRange {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

          int count = 0;
          System.out.println( Range(count));                                                         

     }

     public static int Range (int count) {

          int min = 2;
          int max = 10;

          for ( int i = 0; i < max ; i++) {

               System.out.println(Range(count));
               Range(count);
          }
          return (0); 
     }
}
```

Getting `stack overflow` error on the recursive function.

Comment: You will need to have a stopping condition for the recursive function. Otherwise the recursive function will keep running for ever.

Comment: How do i do that? How do i make it stop? Which line should i added it too?

Comment: Maybe for practice try some useful recursion problem

Comment: I think it would be better if you first make up your mind what a recursive method should look like. You can find an easy-to-read article for example under [Recursion In Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-recursion)

Comment: recursive problem where can i find it?

Comment: Let me read it up first. I get back here if i still don't understand but thank you.

Comment: @NISHANAJIHAH Can you accept one of the below or explain why those answers dont work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defeating the purpose of recursion by using a `for` loop.

There are three most important things about a recursive function/method:

1. The terminating condition.
2. The value with which the method/function is called recursively.
3. Where (before/after the recursive call) to process the parameter(s).

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        range(2, 10);
    }

    public static void range(int min, int max) {
        if (max <= min - 1) {// The terminating condition
            return;
        }
        range(min, max - 1);// The recursive call
        System.out.print(max + " ");// Processing the parameter(s)
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

On a side note, you should always follow the [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. the name of the method should be `range` instead of `Range`.

Comment: Why some code use **+1** and some **-1** and in `System.out.print(max + " ");` use the `(max + " ")` i don't understand this **+** things

Comment: @NISHANAJIHAH - For a recursive function you want a base condition after that there won't be a recursive call. So to met base condition either you need to keep incrementing from min to reach max so +1 or need to keep decrementing from max to reach min so -1

Comment: @Arvind if someone calls  range(10, 2); by mistake, your code will never meet base condition and will throw stackoverflow

Comment: @Swetank what do you mean by base condition?

Comment: @NISHANAJIHAH Base condition is also know as terminating condition, that means from where your stack starts popping, if you don't have base condition then recursive call will be infinite and result into stack memory full and throw stackoverflow error

Comment: @Swetank i see infinity looping. i understand need a termination condition.

Answer (score 3):

try something like below here you can stop at current >= maximum.
Please find the inline comments of what code does .

```
public class MethodsRecursiveRange {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Range(2,10); // Start
    }

    public static int Range (int curr, int max) {
        System.out.println(curr);   // Print the current value
        if(max<=curr) {             // Check if the Current value is greater or equal to Maximum limit
            return 0;               // Stop the recursion with 0 as return value
        } 
        return Range(++curr,max);   // Continue recursion with keeping max same, increment current value and invoke Range 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to do in a recursive method is have a terminating condition. If the condition is true, the method terminates. If the condition is false, the method calls itself but changes its arguments. In the below code, it is actually the other way round. If the condition is true, the method calls itself and if the condition is false, the method terminates.

```java
public class Tester {
    private static void printNum(int num, int limit) {
        if (num <= limit) {
            System.out.printf("%d ", num);
            printNum(num + 1, limit);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printNum(2, 10);
    }
```

Initially the method is invoked from method `main()` with the starting number and the ending number. In the initial invocation, `num` = 2 and `limit` = 10. This means the condition is true so the number 2 is printed with a single space after it. Then the same method is called but with the first argument equal to 3 and the second argument the same, i.e. 10.

So in the second invocation, `num` = 3 and `limit` = 10. The method then prints 3 with a single space after it and then calls itself with arguments 4 and 10.

Eventually the method `printNum()` is called with `num` = 11 and `limit` = 10 which means the condition [ `if (num <= limit`) ] is false so the method does not call itself and prints a newline. Once the method does not call itself, the recursion stops.

If a recursive method does not have a terminating condition it will keep calling itself. Each call requires memory to store local method variables and other things. So each recursive call means your program requires more memory. Java puts a limit on how many recursive calls you can make. Once you pass that limit, Java throws a [StackOverflowError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) and terminates your program forcibly.

Comment: Wow thank you for the explanation i understand but i still don't understand how to stop the looping of the recursive. Is there a easier code where i can easily understand how it stop and what you say to stop the recursive looping you need to call back the methods it is? but isn't it the same as you do methods it self by calling return.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to print from min to max recursively, so for a recursive function it is important to have a base condition from where your code will stop recursive calls and start popping the stack. So in below code you are calling recursive function Range with min and max and here Range function will get call every-time until base condition met and print you count which is +1 for each call and keep pushing on stack. Once base condition is met it just starts popping and and code will end successfully.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Range(min, max)
    Range(2, 10);
}

public static void Range(int count, int max) {
    System.out.println(count);

    // Base condition
    if(count >= max) return;

    // Recursive call
    Range(count + 1, max);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know is to do it like this.

- if `min <= max` print min and call range with updated min
- else return.

```
range(2,10);

public static void range(int min, int max) {
    if (min <= max) {
       System.out.print(min + " ");
       range(min+1, max);
    }
}
```

It works like this.

- first call from main program.
- **range entered.**
- min = 2 and max = 10
- is min <= max?
- yes so print min which is 2
- now call range with 3 and 10 (previous min +1)
- **range entered**
- min = 3 and max = 10
- is min <= max ?
- yes so print min which is 3
- now call range with 4 and 10  (previous min + 1)
- **range entered**
- min = 4 and max = 10
- if min <= max ?
- yes so print min which is 4
- now call range with 5 and 10 (previous min + 1)
- continue in this fashion until `min > max`

Eventually min > max and the whole call stack will unwind and return to the calling program.

Comment: in the code why does it have to **+1** in the `range (min+1, max);`

Comment: Because I am calling the program again.  The next time I call it, min will be 3 and 3 will be printed.  Then 4 then 5.  When min == max it will start returning thru the call stack and eventually return to where it was first invoked.  Think if it this way.  If you simply called the range method 5 times in a row with min increased by 1 value each time with no recursion, you would iterate thru those values.  But recursion is when a program calls itself.

Comment: I modified my answer with an explanation.

Comment: I understand it is a bit clearer thank you very much @WJS